# ASP.NET MVC with React as Frontend deployment best practice

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, react-router

I have recently rewritten one ASP.net MVC project to replace razor with React as the front end. And pretty much follow the steps in this post: https://dev.to/dance2die/setting-up-a-react-environment-for-aspnet-mvc-44la. The local testing is fine until I started to deploy onto the IIS server. And because there will be a virtual path/subdirectory IIS will assign for each web application. My app root has become something like http://server/MyApp while in local it is http://localhost:port/.  This breaks the followings

1. The react-router break, this could be fixed by add a basename like `<BrowserRouter basename="/myApp">`. But this seems will break the application running in local
2. The HTTP calls break, anything like `axios.post('/someController/someMethod/'..` will need to be changed to `axios.post('/myApp/someController/someMethod/'..` to make it works on IIS server

Bear with me with those basic questions as I'm pretty new in both areas. Thanks a lot in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you deploying this in a subfolder of the root of the website? Deploying to IIS should not cause a subdirectory to be added to the path. That's an internal detail. From the application's perspective, paths are relative to the root. It sounds like you are not configuring IIS correctly.

Comment: @JuanR Because we have some other applications running on the IIS server. So each application has a path like http://serverName/app1, http://serverName/app2

Comment: If they are actual applications, the different roots should be managed using host headers, not paths, unless what you call "applications" are actually more like modules that share a common app domain/root in which case the routing should be configured at the root level anyways.

Comment: For instance, if these are considered separate apps, the host headers would be something along the lines of app1.servername.com and app2.servername.com, each mapping to their corresponding application root.